# How can I delete duplicate records in Generic Inquiry?

Tags: acumatica

I created a custom generic inquiry but I have not found a way to put an instruction like SQL Distinct statement to delete duplicate records.

Could you help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Group by to your key field in the Group by tab.

Comment: Thanks, adding a group by to my primary key solved my problem, have a nice day!